# Menu Text doesn't appear in my Android menu

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

The text doesn't show up in my android menu, only the icon. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

**XML menu file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/context_menu_favourites"
        android:icon="@drawable/dash_fav_btn"
        android:title="Favourites" 
        android:titleCondensed="Fav"
        />
</menu>
```

The **inflater code** in my activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This sometimes happens when the icon is too big... what's the size of the icon?

Comment: 96x96. I guess I should shrink it down then?

Comment: @Cristian : Just did that and it worked! Thanks :) There is no way of making it display text with both large icon, other than making a custom menu...? Make this an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sometimes happens when the icon is too big... as you just confirmed, that's the case. And no, if you want to use a bigger icon, you will have to implement a menu yourself.